# Shopify Restore Deleted product

Tags: rails-activerecord, shopify, webhooks

I am working on application which interact to Shopify::API.I want to remove unnecessary (Quite OLD) product.It i will run **ShopifyAPI::Product.delete(ID)**, I can make successful deletion of product from shopify store.

But some times there is a change that i have deleted wrong product, so is it any possible way to restore/re-create That product

One way is i can store all product in my local db before deleting from store,but how can i create on store again, Does WEBHOOK can help me OR active record rollback or some thing else can be help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no direct way to restore products that were deleted.
If you have the product data saved locally, you can re-create the product through the Shopify API. Notice however the product will be new (new Shopify id) and will be missing metafields and missing images if they were hosted on Shopify, unless you save those objects too!

There exists apps in the app store that facilitate backing up stores and allow restoring information as well.

Ex: [rewindit.io](http://rewindit.io)

Cheers.